# PHP errors where they shouldn't be! (Online server)

Tags: php

My server online has PHP 5.6 and the same script works completely fine in my other directories but for some reason I keep getting error 500's when I try to go on the website and all the server is giving back is this:

```
[24-Jan-2016 08:52:08 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/starl607/public_html/revisionplanner/php/database/connect.php on line 1

[24-Jan-2016 08:53:37 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/starl607/public_html/revisionplanner/php/database/connect.php on line 1

[24-Jan-2016 08:54:11 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/starl607/public_html/revisionplanner/php/database/connect.php on line 1
```

(This is from a separate log file)

But this is what my code looks like:

```
    <?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function databaseerror() {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>RevisionPlanner - Could Not Connect!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nodb.css">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="favicon.ico">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="main">
                <img src="images/icons/dberror.png">
                </br>
                <p>There Was An Error While Trying To Connect To The Database! Try Reloading The Page.</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    die;
}

if ($ip === '::1') {
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=revisionplanner', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        $status = $db->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);

    } catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo databaseerror();
    }
} else {

}
?>
```

Why is this error happening? If I remove all the content in the page, it works fine but without doing that, removing segments of code doesn't work.

Comment: Use something in else conditions else { echo 0;
}

Comment: Nope... :( See how it makes no sense!

Comment: Using the same htaccess file in the new folder?

Comment: Do you have some scripting before this file is used like an include?